# Eliminar una fila de una tabla con javascript

Tags: javascript, html5, dom

Quisiera saber cómo eliminar una fila de una tabla, mediante un botón en cada fila, a continuación dejo un código pero no estaría entendiendo porque no funciona:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const btnBorrar = document.getElementById("btnBorrar")
  
    btnBorrar.addEventListener("click", () => {
        const fila = document.createElement("fila")
        table.appenChild(btnBorrar);
        btnBorrar.addEventListener("click", evt => evt.target.remove());
    });
});
```

Comment: y que error aparece? en la consola o cual es el comportamiento inesperado que sucede al ejecutar el evento.

Comment: `createElement('fila')` crea un elemento `<fila>`, lo que no tiene mucho sentido. De todos modos no lo usas para nada. El botón, por otro lado, se borra a si mismo

Comment: en la consola aparece el siguiente error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
    at gestionEstudiantes.js:97:13

Answer (score 0):

Tengo otra forma de implementar la misma función, si aún no llegue tarde.

En cada botón en cada fila `td` hay un llamada a la función del trabajo a realizar.

```
<button onclick="eliminar(this)">Eliminar</button>
```

Y la función aparenta así:

```
  let row = Id.parentNode.parentNode;
  let table = document.getElementById("table"); 
  table.deleteRow(row.rowIndex);
```

Y el ejemplo funcional es el siguiente

```js
function eliminar(Id) {
  
  let row = Id.parentNode.parentNode;
  let table = document.getElementById("table"); 
  table.deleteRow(row.rowIndex);

};
```

```css
            
table {
width: 100%;
caption-side: bottom;
border-collapse: collapse;
vertical-align: top;
}

table * {
padding: 0.5rem 0.5rem;
border: 1px solid #777
}

table tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
background-color: #ccc
}
```

```html
            
<table id="table">
        
        <thead>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Opción</th>
        </thead>
        
        <tr> 
            <td>Fila uno td</td> 
            <td>Segunda fila</td> 
            <td><button onclick="eliminar(this)">Eliminar</button></td> 
        </tr> 
        
        <tr> 
            <td>Uno</td> 
            <td>Dos</td> 
            <td><button onclick="eliminar(this)">Eliminar</button></td> 
        </tr>
        
        <tr> 
            <td>Uno</td> 
            <td>Dos</td> 
            <td><button onclick="eliminar(this)">Eliminar</button></td> 
        </tr>
        
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

A pesar de que la pregunta ya se respondio, quisiera agregar otra forma de hacer lo mismo

Se crea una tabla como cualquier otra

```
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Algo</th>
                <th>Algo 2</th>
                <th>Algo 3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Dato1</td>
                <td>Dato2</td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="eliminar">Eliminar</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Dato1</td>
                <td>Dato2</td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="eliminar">Eliminar</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Dato1</td>
                <td>Dato2</td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="eliminar">Eliminar</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Y para eliminar cada fila, se haria de la siguiente manera:

```javascript
document.querySelectorAll('.eliminar').forEach(boton => { //Se obtienen todos lo elementos con clase eliminar
        boton.addEventListener('click', () => {//Obtenemos el boton de cada fila y se agrega el evento click
            const tr = boton.parentNode.parentNode //Accedemos al tr de cada boton
            tr.remove() //Eliminamos la fila
        })
    });
```